# Send transactions failed due to timeout when creating Channel on Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

I'm executing this code https://github.com/IBM/blockchain-application-using-fabric-java-sdk. When I execute CreateChannel I get this error :

> Send transactions failed. Reason:  timeout

I checked the log of the `orderer.example.com docker` container and it seems to be no communication. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Channel create command times out when the orderer takes long enough (>5s), to respond to the transaction. You can add `--timeout duration` to increase the default value. I faced similar issue while creating a channel through command line - https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/commands/peerchannel.html#peer-channel-create

You can check if java SDK provides an equivalent configuration in the channel apis for peers.